# Should rails action names contain underscores like: get_user or getUser or getuser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How should I name a action if it contains 2 words:

```
word_other
wordOther
wordother
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're talking about controller actions? In that case, they need to be underscored: `get_user`.

The convention is for variable and method names to be underscored: `@new_instance.get_user`. This ensures that controller methods map cleanly to actions. It also improves readability and helps distinguish `method_names` from `ClassNames`

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby, method names have the convention that they should be separated by underscores, so Rails action names are no different.

Answer (score 1):

It should be with underscore: `word_other`.

Rails action name is actually just a method name and Ruby's convention for method name is in lower case with words separated by underscore.

I was trying to find an official statement about this, but unfortunately I couldn't find it. But you can have a look at the [methods](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/fr_method_index.html) available in Ruby Core to see how Ruby methods are named. There's also a write up on the [naming convention](http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=7) for both Ruby and Rails.

With Rails, naming convention is even more important because one of the philosophy of Rails is [convention over configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails#Philosophy_and_design). For example, if your controller class name is `BookShopsController`, you need to use `book_shops` to refer to it in your routes.

```
resources :book_shops
# or
match 'book_shops/:id' => 'book_shops#show'
```

If you don't follow along with the convention, you may find that things are more difficult to work with or it may not work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You should name it `word_other`.

In short:

- methods and variables: `all_lower_case_seperated_by_underscores`
- class- and module-names: `CamelCased`
- constants: `UPPERCASE`

[This article](http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=7) is very good summary of the ruby and rails naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

In general, ruby identifiers should use `snake_case` rather than `camelCase`. However, Rails action names should be selected from a much smaller list: `show, index, new, create, edit, update, destroy`. That is to say that following [RESTful conventions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) will lead you to a simpler system that more accurately reflects the semantics of the web and allows you to more cleanly model your domain's resources and should be preferred to other action naming 'systems'.

Comment: while this is true, i don't think it addresses the question. There are plenty of times when custom actions are needed.